# Implementing a classification on Google Earth Engine

Tags: classification, google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I am attempting to implement a classification based from a decision tree (attached as image below) where there are 5 classes. These classes are based off the different water reflectance values in Landsat 8 bands (namely NIR, Red and Green). I have no idea how I should go about doing this. Someone suggested using image.expression however it has not worked for me. This is the code I've used thus far:
(landsat is landsat 8 surface reflection)

```js
var image = ee.Image(landsat.filterDate ('2018-01-01', '2018-03-01').filterBounds(point).sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());

//print image 
print('a landsat scene', image);

//implement MNDWI

var green = image.select('B3');
var swi = image.select('B6');
var mndvi = green.subtract(swi).divide(green.add(swi)).rename('MNDWI');

var mndvipara = {min: 0, max: 0.7, palette: ['white', 'blue']};


Map.addLayer(mndvi, mndvipara, 'MNDVI image');

//classification attempt 
var lpb =image.expression (
'nir > 0.018', {
'nir': image.select ('B5')});
Map.addLayer (lpb, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['FF0000', '00FF00']});
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKSbZ.png (if image doesn't work, classification can be found at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0303243415000641 - Figure A.1

Comment: What exactly did not work? Is the result unexpected, did you receive an error message or is there an issue with the `.expression()` function?

Comment: Check [this example](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://code.earthengine.google.com/f98cb96e6a0c5f54b16929956ef18713&sa=D&ust=1520351878270000&usg=AFQjCNEYc07O_5-TndPgOKhOWRkWkI2KyQ) to know how to use GGE decision tree

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [ee.Image.expression()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageexpression) to implement a classification decision tree. Although it is unclear which Landsat 8 image collection you are using, if it is the Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance collection you will need to include the scaling factor in the calculation:

```js
var lpb = image.expression(
  'nir > 0.018', 
  {
    'nir': image.select('B5').multiply(0.0001)
  }
);
```

While using ee.Image.expression() will work, it may be cleaner to implement this decision tree using a series of [conditional or boolean operators](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_relational).

Answer (score 0):

classification in GEE has already a function Decision Tree that can classify your image according to your condition , this is it : *ee.Classifier.decisionTree(treeString)*
in the `treeString` try to write your conditions in the text format generated by R and other similar tools.